# How to kill a bronze colossus?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

A bronze colossus just showed up on my map?  How can I kill it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done this before, get it to go into a room close the door, build walls over the door and quickly flood the room with magma.

Answer (score 4):

So the short answer is, you don't.

Bronze Colossus do not accumulate wounds, so any wound that isn't instantly fatal is shrugged off.  There is one record of someone doing it: [Fluffy wambler](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=56935.0), but I doubt it'll be helpful.

You can consider Pouring magma on it, but it will take a while to melt.  If you have a tame Dragon that might work.  Freezing it in obsidian is a good idea, as obsidian is near unbreakable.

Megabeasts are tough, I feel for you.  But it's all part of the "[fun](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Fun)."

Comment: Aren't they getting more killable in 0.31.09?

Comment: I know they're scheduled to be, I don't know if it'll happen though.

Comment: Please use the @<UserName> when replying to a comment.  That way it shows up in my responses.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, it is possible to kill one through excessive force of arms. My 20 elite dwarves in full steel with steel axes were able to kill one, *eventually* and after heavy losses.

[image: Screenshot]

I don't think this was the result of cumulative damage as much as removal of an essential body part.

Cutting the head off of anything kills it, and apparently catastrophic dismemberment is the only way to kill colossi.