# Strategy for killing a Bronze Colossus?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

So my adventure character is about to go fight a Bronze Colossus. Is there anything I should know or do before I go to fight?
My character is an Axeman, who is fairly good at ambushing if that helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to kill a bronze colossus?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/267/how-to-kill-a-bronze-colossus)

Comment: Might be different, this is adventure the other one is dwarf mode. Its two completely different strategies.

Comment: @Zdrok Yeah I saw that, but many of the suggestions involved pouring lava on him, or just use a highly trained dwarf army. Both of which I cannot do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly you want to throw things at him. Throwing is kinda weird; it doesn't usually do a ton of damage but it's *extremely* high variance. There is one well-documented case of an adventurer killing a bronze colossus by decapitating it with a thrown fluffy wambler; obviously this is pretty unlikely but throwing rocks at it will eventually kill it.

Getting into melee with a bronze colossus is much less random... and that's bad for you, because the BC is many times your size and strength. You're probably faster though so just stay away.

Comment: Said Fluffy er... Wambling of the Colossus happened before the combat rewrite, however.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer Yes, that's true. Using actual weapon-like objects should still at least cause cumulative damage, though, which I know affects colossi. I never said this would be a fast strategy, just relatively safe.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small tip here, DO NOT fight anything near lava. This is especially good against a bronze colossus, where it will most likely either knock you into or against **A N Y T H I N G !!!** Getting knocked against a wall will either stun you, or it will kill you by explosion of body parts, and getting knocked into water or lava is self-explanatory. However, if you can SOMEHOW knock the bronze colossus in lava, it kill him before he gets out (you know? Cause he's a METAL colossus?).

You will miss out on that bronze statue he drops though.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot, He seems to be weak(er) against lashers than most other equips.

Comment: You are allowed to edit your answers. And yes, whips and scourges are effectively lightsabers in DF due to massive velocity and tiny contact area.